# Loopback app.models.ModelName is undefined

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

Below code is accessing one model from another model, which returns undefined

```
var app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(Regions) {
    const Media = app.models.Media;
    console.log( Media) // Returns Undefined
}
```

And I have tried below also, but same error

```
module.exports = function(Regions) {
     console.log( Regions.app.models.Media) // Returns Undefined
}
```

Comment: This sample code should work. Did you add the Media model in your server/model-config.json?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing your model like so:

`require('loopback').getModel('Regions')`

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```js
module.exports = function (Region) {
  let app
  
  Region.beforeRemote('find', function (ctx, unused, next) {
    // Do something
    next()
  })
  
  Region.on('attached', function (a) {
    app = a
  })
}
```

You can also create a boot script if you want to perform actions across models at boot time:

Answer (score 0):

Is your sample code correctly located in **common/models/regions.js**?

Here is some other snippet for you:

```
'use strict';

var app = require('../../server/server');
var models = app.models;
var Media;
app.on('started', function () {
    Media = models.Media;
});

module.exports = function (Regions) {

    ...

}
```